# Chain rule probability with chained information

Tags: probability

I have an ordered set of informations given by the picture below and from these arrows, I need to deduce $\mathbb P(X,Y,Z), \mathbb P(X,Z), \mathbb P(X,Y), \mathbb P(Y,Z)$.

I don't understand what to write except the simple definition of joint probability, how do these arrows influence the definition? There are more questions like this in my exercises with different figures like that (more informations sets and different arrows), these arrows definitely imply something about the definition of joint probability. Thanks.[image]

Comment: If I understand well the picture say that $Y$ is depedent of $X$, if so you can write $P(X,Y) = P(Y|X) P(X)$. The other cases have to be similiar.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari I see the exercise is much simpler than I thought lol thank you :)